# My Hdri backround isnt showing up in render for some camera angles

Tags: rendering, hdri

My water fluid simulation has multiple camera angles, when i render as an animation my the first 59 frames render correctly from one camera angle.
[image: good render 1]

When the camera changes at frame 60 the hdri backround becomes a solid color. What do I do?
[image: bad render 2]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you´ve animated the cycles properties for "CAMERA" in object properties. It is on up until frame 59 and frame 60 it is animated off. Remove animation on that checkbox.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean and am not sure where to find what you are talking about